# declare a C function as friend inside CPP class

Tags: c++, c

I need to use private variable of a class inside a C function. 
I was doing something like this

```
class Helper
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    std::getName(){return name;}
friend extern "C" void initializeHelper();
};
```

but this code segment gives error `unqualified-id before string constant
  extern "C" {`

I am not able to identify what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  A C function can't access class members, because it doesn't know about classes.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth "C" function implemented and compiled as C++ module for sure can,`" èxtern "C"`` is for "C"linkage, not for "C"implementation...

Comment: @DietmarKühl: what is a "C function implemented in C++"?  Are you talking about a free C++ function with C linkage?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Then in that case, I agree that it does make sense ;)

Comment: freelance  C-like functions doesn't have to be extern C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just forward-declare this function before your class:

```
extern "C" void foo();
```

Then you can use it in friend-declaration:

```
class A {
public:
  A() {}
private:
  friend void foo();
  int a;
};
```