# Declare C function friend of class and return C enumerator

Tags: c++, c, friend

This is *very* simliar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29059072/192993), however, the function I am trying to make a friend returns an C enumerator. I cannot figure out the correct syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  enum X {ONE};
  int foo();
  X bar();
}

namespace a {
class A {
public:
  A(int a): a(a) {}
private:
  friend int ::foo();
  friend X ::bar();  // Doesn't work
  int a;
};
}

extern "C" {
 int foo() {
  a::A a(1);
  std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
  return ONE;
}
 X bar() {
  a::A a(2);
  std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
  return ONE;
}
}

int main()
{
  foo();  // outputs: 1
  bar();  // doesn't compile
}
```

The `friend X ::bar();` doesn't work. What is the correct syntax for that.

[Online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7f64e7ddf63cc39)

```
main.cpp:20:18: error: 'enum X' is not a class or a namespace
   friend X ::bar();
                  ^
main.cpp:20:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'bar' with no type     [-fpermissive]
main.cpp: In function 'X bar()':
main.cpp:22:7: error: 'int a::A::a' is private
   int a;
       ^
main.cpp:35:18: error: within this context
   std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean by that? I'm guessing compiler errors, but it would help a lot if you could tell us the errors. Verbatim, complete and unedited please.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - sorry, have updated the answer with the output from the online demo

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make friends out of functions/types with C linkage like you're attempting. Perhaps someone knows the precise answer. But if you face a scenario where it seems impossible, you can always have `bar` call another function without C linkage/symbol names and make _that_ a friend.

Comment: @Ike - it's fine with `foo` as that has a `int` return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding parenthesis to resolve parsing ambiguity

```
friend X (::bar)();
```

Comment: Yay! Thanks! Stack Overflow is so awesome.